# Determining why $\int_{\partial R} z\ dz = 0$ and $\int_{\partial R} z\ dz = 0$ independently of Cauchy's Theorem for a Rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $R$ be a rectangle on the complex plain and $\partial R$ its closed curve.  Without making use of Cauchy's Theorem for a Rectangle (or any of the other Cauchy theorems), I'm curious why we know already that in the follow special cases, Cauchy's Theorem for a Rectangle holds:

$$
\tag{1}
\int_{\partial R} 1\ dz = 0
$$

$$
\tag{2}
\int_{\partial R} z\ dz = 0
$$

Ahlfors makes a passing remark that it has something to do with the fact that $1$ and $z$ are the derivatives of $z$ and $z^2/2$ respectively.  Is his implication, then, that $1\ dz = 1\ dx + i\ dy$ and $z\ dz = z\ dx + iz\ dy$ are **exact differentials** and hence since $\partial R$ is a closed curve, we have that these integrals must equal zero?

Comment: I appreciate the explanations below.  I'm curious also if the explanation I offered above makes any sense as well.  Is this the case?

Comment: That is the essence of what I stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of path integral implies that if $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a $C^1$ path, and $f$ is differentiable, then $\int_{\gamma} f'(z) dz = \int_0^1 f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt= f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))$. Then it follows directly that if you have a piecewise $C^1$ closed curve, the integral of a derivative over it must be zero.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from Stokes' Theorem (these conditions are met by compactness and rectifiability which one needs to verify) once one shows that $dw = 0$, since closed implies exact in this case (star-convex). This is clear in the first case. Now, in the second case $$d(z\; dx + iz\; dy) = -i dx \wedge dy + i dx \wedge dy = 0,$$ which is just multivariable calculus.